# How to filter text in a google body docs to change its style?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, latex

I want to filter a Latex text that comes from a Google Docs first to remove tags like `\section{}` or even to change the style in Google Docs. The real purpose is to transform a Latex source code into a real google docs.

```
\section{La Région-capitale : une place et un rôle exceptionnels}
\subsection{Une longue construction historique}
\subsection{Région-capitale, État et pouvoir politique}
\subsection{Une Région au cœur du pouvoir économique et financier}
\section{De profondes mutations démographiques et économiques}
\subsection{Une région jeune, dynamique et attractive}
\subsection{Un marché du travail et de la formation métropolitain}
\subsection{Le système productif francilien et ses dynamiques}
\begin{itemize}
    \item La première r agricole avec un tiers de la
valeur ajoutee nationale grace aux sols tres fertiles de sa vaste cuvette sedi-mentaire.
    \item L'industrie francilienne se caractérise par le poids des grands groupes, un vaste tissu de petites et moyennes entreprises et l'importance des petites entre prises innovantes
    \item Les services périproductifs et les services aux entreprises sont en plein boom depuis trois décénies
    \item Dans les transports l'IdF est le premier noeud logistique national et un carrefour des échanges nationaux européens et internationaux
    \item I’ile-de-France s'afirme comme la premiére r touristique nationale
\end{itemize}
```

At the moment I think that I can only remove the labels with the following code:

```
function myFunction() {
  // Open a document by ID.
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  //
  body.replaceText("\section", "");
}
```

Therefore **how to change the style of the text between the tags and remove them ?**

Comment: So what is the actual problem or question here?

Comment: @JamesD The question is : "How to change the style of the text between the tags and remove them ?"

Comment: In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide a result you want as a sample? I think that it will help users think of about your issue.